# Check if Char is in range

Tags: c++, char, range, hex

If I have a range of say `000080-0007FF`
and I want to see if a char containing hex is within that range, how can I do it?

Example

```
char t = 0xd790;

if (t is within range of 000080-0007FF) // true
```

Answer (score 8):

```
wchar_t t = 0xd790;

if (t >= 0x80 && t <= 0x7ff) ...
```

In C++, characters are interchangeable with integers and you can compare their values directly.

Note that I used `wchar_t`, because the `char` data type can only hold values up to 0xFF.

Comment: I tried it and I get
warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type Ok just read your fix

Comment: It sounds like your compiler is set to interpret 'char' as a signed data type (which ranges from -128 to 127). Use wchar_t as I edited my answer.

Comment: Is there another way other than wchar_t?

Comment: yes, use a short which is 16 bits.   Actually you really should be using unsigned values.  So unsigned short.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned short t = 0xd790;

if (t >= 0x80 && t <= 0x7ff) ...
```

Since a char has a max value of 0xFF you cannot use it to compare anything with more hex digits than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since hex on a computer is nothing more than a way to print a number (like decimal), you can also do your comparison with plain old base 10 integers.

```
if( (t >= 128) && (t <= 2047) )
{
}
```

More readable.

Comment: No. I would disagree. The Hex values are more readable. You can see the bit patterns from the hex values.

Comment: Readability is entirely dependent on context. If the bit patterns are relevant to the problem at hand hex is more readable (presumably this is the OP's case). If the numbers represent something like normal counts of items, decimal is more readable.